# Matlab FIR filter numerator coefficients to python

Tags: matlab, filters, filter-design, python, finite-impulse-response

I created a equiripple FIR filter in Matlab using `filterDesigner` and exported it to an ASCII file. The file contains the numerator values as a list of 51 numbers tagged under `Numerator:` (this is all the data the file has)

Now I read this 51 values into a python array named `num` and try to recreate the filter in python using [scipy.signal.lfilter](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter.html)

```
from scipy import signal

x_filt = signal.lfilter(num, np.ones_like(num), x)  # x is my input signal
```

This is my original signal

[image]

Here's the filtered signal from **Matlab** (Fpass-800Hz, Fstop-1200Hz)

[image]

But this is what I get from the python code using `scipy.signal.lfilter`

[image]

Can somebody please show me what I am doing wrong here?

---

**EDIT:** (After getting the answer) Here's the correct python code

```
x_filt = signal.lfilter(num, 1, x)
```

Comment: You don't want `np.ones_like(num)` in the denominator.  That's making a denominator of all ones, with lots of possibly unstable poles.  Your denominator in Python needs to be `[1,0,0,0,0,0,...]`. Or just `[1]` if possible.

Comment: It worked. thanks. Can you please add this as an answer?

Comment: Done!  Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want `np.ones_like(num)` in the denominator.  That's making a denominator of all ones, with lots of possibly unstable poles.  Your denominator in Python needs to be `[1,0,0,0,0,0,...]`. Or just `[1]` if possible.